# Using Sharepoint 2013 Task Lists

Tags: sharepoint-online, tasks, task-list

When I open a filtered Online Sharepoint Task List, I lose the ability to modify (insert, indent, move etc) the list in its full "Edit" mode. With the error message: *"We can't modify hierarchy on a view that is sorted/filtered/grouped. Switch views and give it another try."*

**Show every completed and uncompleted task** = too hard to read -- therefore won't be use
**Only show relevant tasks** = too hard to navigate around, bulk edit, indent and move tasks -- therefore tasks won't be updated and data won't be relevant, so it won't be used

The theoretical work arounds I've thought of:

- When a task completes, move it from the live task list to a completed task list
- Delete the task when it's completed ("moving" seemed too difficult)
- Manually delete the task when it's complete (at this point, a .txt file would work as well)

What is the suggested method for having a task list, but still being able to leverage shortcuts?

Comment: Did you end up implementing any of these?  I have the exact same question.  Thanks!

Comment: Nope. I feel like it shouldn't be this hard to use their provided shortcuts...

Comment: I recently found this. their work around is toggling between two tabs (aka views). brilliant. http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/t/197488.aspx

Answer (score -1):

List->Modify view, and look if you have a sort column ("First sort by the column"). Put it "none".